# WCF Authentication Service - How to generate client using Apache Axis?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, forms-authentication, axis

I have an ASP.NET application hosting a few WCF services, using ASP.NET Membership for security.  I've exposed the System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService through an SVC file (AuthenticationService.svc) as shown below:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" %>
```

My WCF configuration for this service is as follows:

```
<service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationServiceBehaviors">
  <endpoint contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</service>

...

<behavior name="AuthenticationServiceBehaviors">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
  <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>

...

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding allowCookies="true"></binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've enabled the authentication service in my web.config as shown below:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="false"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I created a .NET console application to test the service. Visual Studio generated a client, and the service worked as expected. My problem is that I need to use this service from a Java application, but when I try to generate a client in Eclipse using Apache Axis, I get the following error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL: java.io.IOException: Emitter failure.
There is an undefined portType (AuthenticationService) in the WSDL document
http://localhost:17637/Services/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0.
Hint: make sure <binding type=".."> is fully qualified.
```

I've tracked it down to Apache Axis needing different namespace and name in the ServiceContract and ServiceBehavior, thanks to [this post](http://honga.super6.cz/2011/07/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client.html). I've changed other WCF services as that post shows, and they work just fine. The problem is that System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService looks like this (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.applicationservices.authenticationservice.aspx):

```
[ServiceBehaviorAttribute(Namespace = "http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200")]
public class AuthenticationService
```

Notice the ServiceBehaviorAttribute namespace is the same as the ServiceContractAttribute namespace? I need them to be different so I can get Eclipse (Apache Axis) to generate a client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think is possible to change name of built-in service. You should be allowed for wrapping built-in service in other service or for writing custom service handle authentication.

Comment: I ended up rolling my own authentication service a couple years ago for this problem. This has gone unanswered for so long that I did not expect an answer. Thanks!